# N-Queens problem

Tags: code-challenge, combinatorics, chess

In chess, a queen can move as far as as the board extends horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

Given a NxN sized chessboard, print out how many possible positions N queens can be placed on the board and not be able to hit each other in 1 move.

Comment: Do we need to handle 2 <= N <= 4 cases? If so how?

Comment: There is no solution for case: N = 2,3. The wikipedia has a excellent write up about this classic problem. It documents ver well about the solution number from N = 1 to N = 14. (I am still new to Code Golf. Not sure what is the best way to participate yet. :))

Comment: [A000170](http://oeis.org/A000170)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution (originally from [this blog entry](http://nibot-lab.livejournal.com/103551.html)) where I construct a logical description of the solution in conjunctive normal form which is then solved by Mathematica:

```
(* Define the variables: Q[i,j] indicates whether there is a 
   Queen in row i, column j *)
Qs = Array[Q, {8, 8}];

(* Define the logical constraints. *)
problem =
  And[
   (* Each row must have a queen. *)
   And @@ Map[(Or @@ #) &, Qs],
   (* for all i,j: Q[i,j] implies Not[...] *)
   And @@ Flatten[
     Qs /. Q[i_, j_] :>
       And @@ Map[Implies[Q[i, j], Not[#]] &, 
         Cases[Qs, 
          Q[k_, l_] /;
           Not[(i == k) && (j == l)] && (
             (i == k) ||          (* same row *)
                 (j == l) ||          (* same column *)
             (i + j == k + l) ||  (* same / diagonal *)
             (i - j == k - l)),   (* same \ diagonal *)
          2]]]];

(* Find the solution *)
solution = FindInstance[problem, Flatten[Qs], Booleans] ;

(* Display the solution *)
Qs /. First[solution] /. {True -> Q, False -> x} // MatrixForm
```

Here's the output:

```
x   x   x   x   Q   x   x   x
x   Q   x   x   x   x   x   x
x   x   x   Q   x   x   x   x
x   x   x   x   x   x   Q   x
x   x   Q   x   x   x   x   x
x   x   x   x   x   x   x   Q
x   x   x   x   x   Q   x   x
Q   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Ruby

I don't see a `golf` tag, so i'm assuming it's just a challenge.

Here's an implementation of the Algorithm mentioned on Wikipedia. It's not by me, it's at Rosetta Stone and can be found [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/N-queens_problem#Ruby)

CommWikied this Answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Python 2, <strike>190</strike> 185 chars

```
from itertools import*
n=input()
print len(filter(lambda x:all(1^(y in(z,z+i-j,z-i+j))for i,y in enumerate(x)for j,z in enumerate(x[:i]+(1e9,)+x[i+1:])),permutations(range(1,n+1),n)))
```

I just assumed the code golf tag even though it wasn't there. N is read from stdin, the program calculates solutions up to n=10 in acceptable time.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy

```
n=8
s=(1..n).permutations().findAll{ 
  def x=0,y=0
  Set a=it.collect{it-x++} 
  Set b=it.collect{it+y++} 
  a.size()==it.size()&&b.size()==it.size() 
}
```

Delivers a list of all queen solutions like this:

```
[ [4, 7, 3, 0, 6, 1, 5, 2], 
  [6, 2, 7, 1, 4, 0, 5, 3], 
  ... ]
```

For graphical representation add:

```
s.each { def size = it.size()
         it.each { (it-1).times { print "|_" }
                   print "|Q"
                   (size-it).times { print "|_" }
                   println "|"
                 }
         println ""
         }
```

which looks like this:

```
|_|Q|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|Q|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|Q|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|Q|
|_|_|Q|_|_|_|_|_|
|Q|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|Q|_|
|_|_|_|_|Q|_|_|_|
```