# Eight Queens Obsfucation

Tags: code-challenge, chess, obfuscation, popularity-contest

You've probably heard of the classic Eight Queens Puzzle. For those of you who haven't it goes something like this:

> Position 8 queens on an 8×8 chessboard so that no two queens threaten
>   each other (no two queens appear on the same row, column or diagonal
>   as each other).

Here is one answer that is very close:

```
X - - - - - - -
- - - - X - - -
- X - - - - - -
- - - - - X - -
- - X - - - - -
- - - - - - X -
- - - X - - - -
- - - - - - - X
```

As you can see, two queens appear on the long diagonal between the top left corner and the bottom right corner.
Your task is to solve the Eight Queens Puzzle (using any programming language) in a unique or obfuscated manner. The first answer to 15 up-votes wins (the number may be subject to change depending on the popularity of this question).
Your output must be like the example above (empty squares represented by `-`, queens represented by `X` and a space between each `X` or `-`). Good luck!!

Comment: How much obfuscation is required?

Comment: Can I use pre-solved results, or do I HAVE to solve this programmatically? Just wondering because I found a solution in my head pretty quickly.

Comment: It's a popularity contest so, as much or as little as you like @jdstankosky

Comment: This is not very interesting, because there are 12 unique, known solutions. There is no variability at all, so just printing out a solution will always win.  Why not generalize it, like: chess board size and number of queens are taken as input, and the program has to solve or say there is no solution?  Also, why not give a good winning criterion?

Comment: Similar to [http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10/n-queens-problem](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10/n-queens-problem)

Comment: http://www.ioccc.org/1990/baruch.c ..................... http://www.ioccc.org/1990/baruch.hint

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are only 12 possible outputs, and a correct solution just has to print one of them. There's no variation of inputs, and therefore none of outputs.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica

The following implementation challenges the player to find one or more solutions to the eight queens problem. (It was too easy to simply have the program output the answers.)

Clicking on any of the squares in the chessboard toggles between "queen" and .
When `show attacks` is checked, any attacks between queens are highlighted.

The following picture `queenImg`.

[image: queen]

In the board below, no queen attacks another:

[image: queen1]

Placing a fourth queen on a conflicting square results in two reciprocal attacks.

[image: queen2]

The following is one of the solutions.

[image: solution]

```
DynamicModule[{qns = ConstantArray[0, {8, 8}]}, 
Manipulate[
ClickPane[
Dynamic[ArrayPlot[
 Array[Boole[(Mod[#1, 2] == 0 \[And] 
       Mod[#2, 2] == 0) \[Or] (Mod[#1, 2] == 1 \[And] 
       Mod[#2, 2] == 1)] &, {w, w}], 
 ColorRules -> {1 -> White, 0 -> LightBrown}, Mesh -> True,
 Epilog -> {Red, Thickness[.005],
   If[attacks, 
    Line[Cases[
       Tally@Flatten[z[##] & /@ (Reverse /@ Position[qns, 1]), 
         1], {a_, n_} /; n > 1][[All, 1]]], {}], 
   Table[Inset[queenImg, p, Automatic, 10/w], {p, 
     Position[qns, 1] - .5}]}]], (qns = flip[qns, Ceiling@#]) &],
{{attacks, True, "show attacks"}, {True, False}},
Initialization -> (w = 8;
z[{r_, c_}] := {row[r], col[c], diag1[r, c], diag2[r, c]};   
row[r_] := {{0, r - .5}, {8, r - .5}};
col[c_] := {{c - .5, 0}, {c - .5, 8}};
diag1[r_, c_] := {{0, r - c}, {8 - (r - c), 8}};
diag2[r_, c_] := {{0, c + r - 1}, {c + r - 1, 0}};
flip[a_, pos_] := MapAt[(# - 1)^2 &, a, pos])]]
```

Comment: +1, nice program. Perhaps you could add some kind of feature to move the user-entered queens into an acceptable position. Then it would fulfill the challenge, too.

Answer (score 4):

## dc

```
[sSdlS*]sw[d252-lwx26482+lwx1504824-lwx50051569+lwx982283196-lwx10821394332+lwx58071763728-lwx99637122816+]sa10 0:d0[laxd*453%;d1100.8*11552+P1+d8%;dPd64>s]dssx
```

Also at 160 characters it's decently short.

Answer (score 3):

## **Ruby >=1.9**

```
queens = %w[Anne-Marie Mary Elizabeth Victoria Maleficent Gertrude Alexandra Latifa]
SQUARES_ON_A_CHESSBOARD = 64

queens.permutation.find do |succession|
  i = SQUARES_ON_A_CHESSBOARD
  [-1,1].map{ |m| succession.map{ |queen| queens.index(queen) + m*i+=1}}.map(&:uniq).map(&:size).inject(&:*) == SQUARES_ON_A_CHESSBOARD
end.each do |queen|
  r=queens.map{queens[SQUARES_ON_A_CHESSBOARD & 1][SQUARES_ON_A_CHESSBOARD % 10]}
  r[queens.index(queen)]=(queens*SQUARES_ON_A_CHESSBOARD.to_s)[SQUARES_ON_A_CHESSBOARD]
  puts r.join(" ").upcase
end
```

Outputs one solution in the required format.

Comment: The queen names are a nice touch.  :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Ruby

```ruby
Q=8;$><<[*0...Q].permutation.select{|u|u.each_with_index.map{|a,b|[a-b,a+b]}.transpose.map{|z|z.uniq.size}==[Q,Q]}.map{|s|s.map{|f|(["-"]*(Q-1)+["X"]).rotate(f)*"\040"}*$/}*($/*2)
```

A not so much obfuscated but unique code - it contains function uniq ;-) but not a single whitespace! Prints all solutions to console. Maybe I'll start to obfuscate it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

q8 = (sequence_ . (<$> (head.(foldM.flip.const) 
       (\_' -> join<$>sequence [(:[])<$>(((\_''-> [_''|
                 foldr (\(_''',_')->( (((==)<*>(\\[0,_''',-_''']))[_''-_']) &&)) 
                   (((/=)<*>((\\)>>=id)) [_']) $ zip [1..] _'])<$>[1..8])>>=id), 
                   [_'] ]) [] $ [1..8])))
       (\_' -> putStrLn$concat$replicate(_'-1)" -"++[" X"]++replicate(8-_')" -")
```

Output:

```
 - - - X - - - -
 - X - - - - - -
 - - - - - - X -
 - - X - - - - -
 - - - - - X - -
 - - - - - - - X
 - - - - X - - -
 X - - - - - - -
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution in Python. This outputs every possible solution to the problem.

```
from itertools import permutations

def board(vector):
print ("\n".join('- ' * i + 'X ' + '- ' * (8-i-1) for i in vector) + "\n\n= = = = = = = =\n")


cols = range(8)
for vector in permutations(cols):
    if 8 == len(set(vector[i]+i for i in cols)) \
         == len(set(vector[i]-i for i in cols)):
        board (vector)
```

Here is a short sample of the output.

```
X - - - - - - - 
- - - - X - - - 
- - - - - - - X 
- - - - - X - - 
- - X - - - - - 
- - - - - - X - 
- X - - - - - - 
- - - X - - - - 

= = = = = = = =

X - - - - - - - 
- - - - - X - - 
- - - - - - - X 
- - X - - - - - 
- - - - - - X - 
- - - X - - - - 
- X - - - - - - 
- - - - X - - - 

= = = = = = = =

X - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - X - 
- - - X - - - - 
- - - - - X - - 
- - - - - - - X 
- X - - - - - - 
- - - - X - - - 
- - X - - - - -
```

Answer (score 1):

## k

Relatively trivial solutions, For 32 characters:

```
-1'"-X"@0b\:'0x1002200140088004;
```

Slightly better (more painful to read than obfuscated):

```
((-).*:'(c;i))'@'[(*i)#,:(*i)#10h$45i;2/:'i#(*/(i:8 4))_0b\:*/c:7 129790099;:;10h$88i];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python, Obfuscation through Complexity**

Though you would see magic numbers in my code, they are not the hard-coded solution. On running the code, you would get the list of all possible positions of the queens

```
from itertools import*
from math import*
def foo():
    def bar(x):
        k1,k2,k4 = 6148914691236517205L,3689348814741910323L,1085102592571150095L
        x = ((x >> 1) & k1) | ((x & k1) << 1)
        x = ((x >> 2) & k2) | ((x & k2) << 2)
        x = ((x >> 4) & k4) | ((x & k4) << 4)
        return x
    op = [(9259542123273814144L,4,1,0),(9241421688590303745L,7,1,8),(9241421688590303745L,7,-1,-8)]
    for o in op:
        d=o[0]
        m=18446744073709551615L
        for n in range(o[1]):
            yield d
            yield bar(d)&18446744073709551615L
            m=(m<<o[3] if o[3]>0 else m>>-o[3])&18446744073709551615L
            d=(d>>o[2] if o[2]>0 else d<<-o[2])&(m)
for e in (int(''.join("{0:08b}".format(n) for n in p),2) for p in permutations((2**n for n in range(8)),8)):
    if all((round(log(m & e)/log(2),8)).is_integer() for m in foo() if m&e):
        print '\n'.join(''.join(e) for e in  zip(*[iter("{0:064b}".format(e))]*8))
        print '-'*8
```

Comment: You should make all your list comps into `map`s since that's always harder to read

Comment: this is a wrong solution, since it prints positions in which queens attack themselves:
    10000000
    00100000
    00001000
    01000000
    00010000
    00000100
    00000010
    00000001

Answer (score 1):

### Q

Obfuscation through hideousness

```
nq:{
    f:{[]
        b:.[;;:;"X"]/[-1_'16 cut 128#"- ";flip (til 8;2*neg[8]?8)];
        v:{"X" in (x[;first where y="X"] each (til 8) except z)}[b]'[b;til 8];
        d:{"X" in x ./:{$[null r:1+last where raze (1#'x)=7;enlist -1 -1;x til r]}raze 1_{x,/:y}'[rotate[z;til 8];flip@[;(first where y="X")]@/:((+;neg@-)@\:2*til 8)]}[b]'[b;til 8];
        e:{"X" in x ./:{$[null r:1+last where raze (1#'x)=0;enlist -1 -1;x til r]}raze 1_{x,/:y}'[reverse rotate[z+1;til 8];flip@[;(first where y="X")]@/:((+;neg@-)@\:2*til 8)]}[b]'[b;til 8];
        (not any v,d,e;b)};
    while[not first q:f[];];
    -1 last q;
    }
```

.

```
q)nq[]
- - - X - - - -
- - - - - - - X
- - - - X - - -
- - X - - - - -
X - - - - - - -
- - - - - - X -
- X - - - - - -
- - - - - X - -
```

Answer (score 1):

## ⍴Script (rhoScript)

You wanted obfuscated, well...

```
��ˠo����}���e���
```

Hexdump, for obvious reasons:

```
00000000: a991 cba0 6f87 c1fb e97d 82c1 cd65 e2f8  ....o....}...e..
00000010: 90
```

In less-obfuscated form:

```
8 range permutations 
    (with-index 
        (sum) map uniq arg-a with-index 
                (*exploding subtract) map uniq concatenate length) 
keep-maxes-by
```

Yeah, I don't really know what it does either.